# How to get username after login with FORM based authentication

Tags: java, security, weblogic

I am following the link http://middlewaremagic.com/weblogic/?p=2034 to perform form based authentication. I have created a security realm then successfully delegate the authentication check to weblogic 10.3.
Everything is fine, but I could not get username, HttpServletRequest->getRemoteUser() returns null.

Do you have an idea how to get username after login? I am going to use username in every  Managed bean to log user operations.

**EDIT:**
I have found my mistake that I invalidated the session before logging user operation (logout operation), that is why HttpServletRequest->getRemoteUser() returns null. Thanks for contribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found my mistake that I invalidated the session before logging user operation (logout operation), that is why HttpServletRequest->getRemoteUser() returns null. 
Thanks for contribution.

Answer (score 2):

You can obtain it from SecurityContext as well :

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal().getUserName();
```

Comment: in which API SecurityContextHolder class consists

Comment: It is in Spring Security core lib. Here is the path : org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;

Answer (score 1):

Try to get user principal from request and then get name from it. Like this:

```
Principal p = request.getUserPrincipal();
String username = p.getName();
```

Answer (score 1):

`j_username` is available in the `Principe`, so just check there is any `Principle` in the request object.

```
String username;
Principal principal = request.getUserPrincipal();
            if (principal != null) {
                username= principal.getName(); // Find User by j_username.
            }
```

Comment: then there is something wrong in the configuration or authentication is not successful.

Comment: I don't think so, since when I type wrong username/password, I could not see pages