# request.getUserPrincipal() returns null in WebSphere

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere, j-security-check

I am using form based authentication with Websphere app server (j_security_check). I want to log the value of `j_username`. I am not able to do so since I get `request.getUserPrincipal()` as `null`. I am not able to get any methods in `SecurityContextHolder` and I am even getting `request.getRemoteUSer` as `null` even on my error page as configured in web.xml.

Already tried the below things:

1. [How to get username after login with FORM based authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20369034/how-to-get-username-after-login-with-form-based-authentication)
2. [j_security_check need user name to populate form from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13887166/j-security-check-need-user-name-to-populate-form-from-database)
3. http://www.coderanch.com/t/284314/JSP/java/doesn-request-getParameter-username-work

Also, I am not invalidating the session during this process.

Comment: Which WebSphere version are you using - traditional or Liberty? In general, you need to have `Application security` enabled in the server configuration, and correct config in the `web.xml`.